Transimpedance Amplifier Gain ac and S-parameter Analysis
I'm currently working on finding the transimpedance gain of a transimpedance amplifier. However, I've encountered an issue where I get different gains when performing AC analysis compared to S-parameter analysis.
For the S-parameter analysis, I'm using a formula from a specific research paper (Link) to find the gain from S-parameters. The Formula says: $$ Z_T = Z_{O} (S_{21}/(1 - S_{11})) $$
After calculating the gain from the S-parameters, I noticed that the gain is different from what AC analysis gives. I'm unsure if the Formula I'm using is correct or if I'm missing something in my calculations.


I do not terminate the 50-ohm impedance port at the input in the AC analysis.
However, for the S-parameter analysis, I do apply the 50-ohm termination.
Could anyone provide some insight into this? Is there a reason why these two methods would yield different results? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The simulation should also include the 50Ω termination.

@RussellH You mean the AC analysis? If I terminate for AC analysis, the gain will be significantly dropped, which I don't want.

Please refer to my 1991 paper entitled “ Method to find the transimpedance gain for optical receivers” by Ricardo Saad and Rui Fragassi Souza.(SPIE publication).  In that paper, the expression for the transimpedance gain is derived for generic characteristic impedances at the input and the output of the amplifie. The formula you presented is a simplification when Zo1=Zo2=Zo. That is what engineers normally use in the design of transimpedance amplifiers. However, in your case seems to be different. Alternatively, you can use Y-parameters. I use this method in some of my RF graduate classes.

If referring to a paper without an explicit answer, this can be in the comments.
